# Have any Professional course (certification program) for iPhone developer?

Tags: iphone

Have any Professional course (certification program) for iPhone developer? Like MCAD for Microsoft .NET developer and Zend for PHP developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally don't put too much store by certification programs - certainly not over real experience.

If you just want training, Big Nerd Ranch have several iPhone courses. Only in Europe and the US. Schedule is at http://www.bignerdranch.com/schedule.shtml

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any certification program for iPhone developers. But there are some free online resources like this course offered by the [Stanford University](http://www.stanford.edu/):

[CS 193P - iPhone Application Programming](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/index.php)

There are 20 lectures you can download as PDF files.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any certification courses, but to add to the list of places to go to get training, Apple's Worldwide Developers Conference is a great learning experience. In addition to several tracks of technical instruction, they run labs where you can have one-on-one interaction with Apple engineers. I found the whole thing tremendously worthwhile.

http://developer.apple.com/WWDC/

Answer (score 0):

I took a training course in March and recieved my iPhone Developer Certification. It was pretty solid. The link is -  http://www.theunbounded.com/iPhone/iPhone-Developer-Training.asp

Hope this helps.

-Jay